# Convert JValue to String in Lift Scala

Tags: json, scala, parsing, lift

I have json string. I converted it to JValue using net.liftweb.JsonParser

```
val x : JValue =  parse(json)
```

Then i modified the value of a field called "name" using replace()

```
x.replace("name" :: Nil, JString("Tim"))
```

Question is how do i convert this JValue back to a json String

Comment: I think you just use the `write` method from the library on it.

Comment: @Rich Henry: please let me know, write method from which class in the library should i use

Comment: If you imported `org.json4s._` then it likely will already be there. It's part of json4s.

Comment: @Rich Henry: We are using liftweb libraries and Not json4s. Can we acheive this just by using liftweb libraries

Comment: It's better to mention the library you are using in your question (and add a tag).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use this

```
import net.liftweb.json._
compact(render(x))
```

Which will give you a json string version of the JValue object in this form

```
String = {"name":"Tim"}
```

Answer (score 1):

In latest version 3.3.0 as of now in 2018 use below to convert from JsonAST.JValue to json string:

```
import net.liftweb.json._
compactRender(jValue)
```